# loop to search a value and identify in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on this code that checks which cells in a workbook contain the same value of other cells in another workbook through a loop and if there is, it should return color yellow. The code works fine, however there are 2 problems:

1- when I search the value in columns B, if it does not find the value, it returns an error and the macro stops. However, i would like to insert an if to continue the macro if it does not find.

2- The code works fine, but on the last line it is not painting as I wrote on the code.

I would be very happy if you help me. Thank you!!!

```
 Sub tentativa()


 data = Range("H2").Value

 tomas = ("T:\Asset\Backoffice\Rodrigo Bertrand\Operações de RF\Operações Diarias de Renda Fixa\Operações_RendaFixa_" & data & ".xlsx")
 Workbooks.Open tomas

 Workbooks("Selic").Activate

 Worksheets("De Para fundos").Activate

 With Worksheets("De Para fundos")

 Set myRng = .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

 For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
 Workbooks("Selic").Activate

 If .Cells(myCell.Row, "A").Value <> "" Then
 myCell.Copy

 Workbooks(("Operações_RendaFixa_") & data & ".xlsx").Activate


 Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:=myCell, After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection _
    :=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate



ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Select

If ActiveCell.Value = "À vista" Then

EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6



End If

End If

Next myCell

End With
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you're better avoiding any select/activate - use variables to refer to the different workbooks instead of relying on specific files being Active.

```
Sub tentativa()

    Dim Data, tomas, wbT As Workbook, wbS As Workbook, f As Range
    Dim myRng As Range, myCell As Range

    Data = Range("H2").Value

    tomas = "T:\Asset\Backoffice\Rodrigo Bertrand\Operações de RF\" & _
            "Operações Diarias de Renda Fixa\Operações_RendaFixa_" & Data & ".xlsx"

    Set wbT = Workbooks.Open(tomas)
    Set wbS = Workbooks("Selic")

    With wbS.Worksheets("De Para fundos")

        Set myRng = .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            If .Cells(myCell.Row, "A").Value <> "" Then
                'Find() returns Nothing if there's no match, so test for that
                Set f = wbT.Sheets(1).Columns(2).Find(What:=myCell, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    If f.Offset(0, 7).Value = "À vista" Then
                        'EDIT: for debugging
                        Debug.Print "About to highlight Row " & _
                          f.Row & " on sheet '" & f.Parent.Name & _
                          "' of file '" & wbT.Name & "'" 
                        f.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        Next myCell

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim. Thanks for your help, however your code does not work properly. It debugs when you "Set F"

Comment: @user7004 - If that 'orphaned' [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) is not part of `wbT.Sheets(1)`, you will run into problems. The quick way to fix that is to remove `, After:=ActiveCell`.

Comment: Ok. Now it's running, but it still does not highlight the last line! it should return color 6

Comment: Which line is supposed to be highlighted ? The one in "tomas" or the one in "selic" ?

Comment: Then that should work - try placing a breakpoint on `If f.Offset(0, 7).Value = "À vista" Then` and see if it ever enters that block

Comment: i placed the breakpoint and it jumps the line f.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6... That was the problem of the code i put here

Comment: If it never executes that line then the value in Col I on the found row is not = "À vista"

Comment: Sure, but even when is "À vista" it does not highlight